# Different display of the same fonts among Browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem where the same font(same font name & size) appears differently between Internet Explorer and Firefox(and also Chrome & Safari).

This is what IE9 looks like(hopefully the detail is high enough to show the font is thicker/has a higher weight than it should):
[image]

This is what Firefox and etc. look like:
[image]

Is there a CSS reset that will get some uniformity of the font among browsers? Maybe a hack for IE?

Heres the simple HTML of the page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
        body {
            color: RGB(102,102,102);
            font-size: 13px;
            font-family: "Arial", "Helvetica", serif;
        }
    -->
    </style>

</head>
<body>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa...</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which version of Firefox is that?

Comment: Firefox 10.0.2. @GGG I agree with you but I dont have the balls to send that link to my boss :P

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no CSS reset or trick or hack that can make all browsers display fonts the same. The same font is rendered differently in different browsers. Even the same font in the same browser may render differently on different systems.

A CSS reset will help to make the defaults more consistent, which could help if it was for example a headline tag, where some headlines are bold by default and others aren't, and the defaults varies somewhat between browsers. It can't help when the size and weight are set values.

You can make a hack so that it looks the way that you want in some specific browser, but all users of that browser might not need it. While it may look better for some, it might actually make it look worse for others.

---

Side note: I noticed that you use `serif` as fallback for `Arial` and `Helvetica`. You would want to use `sans-serif` so that it will look more similar when the fallback is used.

---

Another side note: I see that you use comments inside the style tags, which was only useful for browsers that didn't understand CSS at all, for example Internet Explorer 1.0.

Answer (score 0):

Try this little trick, it may or may not work depending on the font type, ie: custom font

*..from html5bolierplate*

```
html{
    font-size:100%;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0 0 0 transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Browsers generally have different rendering of fonts (as well as just about everything). You should try using a CSS reset. [Eric Meyer has one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), [YUI has one](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/) as well as several other frameworks. for specifics, you should look for either a "reset" (which zeroes all styles) or a "base" (provides a normalized style)

Answer (score 0):

There's a chance this is a font-weight issue. Try adding something like:

```
p {
  font-weight: 400;
}
```